# Javascript doesn't working in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm using datatables, a plugin in JavaScript to sort, filter, search... of records in a table.

Searching in some foruns, I saw if I set this line below in config/enviroments/production.rb

```
config.serve_static_assets = false
```

to true

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
```

worked and really worked.

But I do not do that, because another JavaScripts works and that way is not recommended.

So, I tested another way, I copied all content in datatables.js and cut directly in my view.

The firts line are the firsts line of datatables.js.

```
<script type="text/javascripts">

 (function(i,zap,p){i.fn.dataTableSettings=[]; var D=i.fn.dataTablesSettings;i.fn...
 ...etc...


 $("#ranking").dataTable({
 sPaginationType: "full_numbers",
 iDisplayLength: 20,
 bFilter: true,
 aLengthMenu: false,
 bLengthChange: false,
 bAutoWidth: false,
 /* fixa os valores da primeira coluna (index) */
 fnDrawCallback: function ( oSettings ) {
 /* Need to redo the counters if filtered or sorted */
   if ( oSettings.bSorted || oSettings.bFiltered ){
     for ( var i=0, iLen=oSettings.aiDisplay.length ; i<iLen ; i++ ){
         $('td:eq(0)', oSettings.aoData[ oSettings.aiDisplay[i] ].nTr ).html( i+1 );
     }
   }
 },
 aoColumnDefs: [
   { bSortable: false, aTargets: [ 0 ] },
   { aTargets: [ 14 ], bVisible: false }
 ],
 aaSorting: [[ 13, 'desc' ]],
 oLanguage: {
   sUrl: "/javascripts/i18n/data_tables_lang.json"
 }
 });
 </script>
```

And again, did not works in production.

I wanna know what does not work in production, well, I copied the code, I'm not using anyother gem like Jammit.

Why does not working?

Answer (score 0):

If that is your exact code, your script tag appears to be incorrect:

```
<script type="text/javascripts">
```

should be

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

Remove the "s" from the end of "javascripts," and see if that works.